# Separate .tmux.conf for ssh connections

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tmux, remote-access

I have a few computers on which I use `tmux` locally as well as remotely (via `ssh` with nested `tmux` sessions). Currently I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> as a prefix on all machines but it's a bit tedious to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>whatever</kbd> as soon as I want to perform more than one action.

Is there a way to configure `tmux` so that when I'm accessing it from my terminal emulator I use the prefix <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and when I'm accessing it from ssh I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or something else) as prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is not changing the prefix and adding the following to my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
```

It simply sends the prefix to the nested `tmux` session when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. I feel kind of dumb for not coming up with this earlier...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `run-shell` feature of tmux.

Create the following shell script named `set-prefix.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]];then
    tmux unbind-key C-b;
    tmux set -g prefix C-a;
    tmux bind C-a send-prefix;
else
    tmux display-message "Not a ssh session"
fi
```

Now add the following line in `.tmux.conf`:

```
run 'bash ~/set_key_bind.sh'
```

Comment: When I created the file, marked it as executable and put the line in the .tmux.conf nothing happened. When I put the line at the end of the .tmux.conf and logged in locally the message showed. But when I connected via ssh, tmux didn't open automatically (my .bashrc ends with `exec $(test -z "$TMUX" && (tmux attach || tmux new-session))`) and when I was in tmux the shortcut C-a didn't do anything. I'm not using the shortcut C-a in my .tmux.conf so that's not the cause.